# Bad interaction between fontspec and some lua code that performs string-related search and replace operations

Tags: luatex, fontspec, programming, lua, selnolig

**Update 2013/05/28**: The [selnolig](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/luatex/latex/selnolig) package is now on the CTAN. Comments and critiques always welcome! If you wish to contact me about any aspects of the package, please use the email address that's given at the bottom of the title page of the package's user guide. (Relative to the state of the package described in the question below, I've managed to squash at least one bug, and I suggest better work-arounds for the remaining bugs -- at least the ones I'm aware of!)

---

I'm in the process of readying a LuaLaTeX package for "official" release to the CTAN, but I need to squash a few remaining bugs first. The bug described in this question concerns incorrect behavior of my package that occurs *if* the `fontspec` package is loaded; if `fontspec` is not loaded, none of the problems described here occur. Obviously, asking potential users of my package *not* to load `fontspec` is not an option. Incidentally, the identifier string of the LuaTeX version on my system is "`beta-0.70.2-2012062819`", distributed with MacTeX2012. For much more information about the full `selnolig` package, which does automated, selective suppression of typographic ligatures, please see [New package, selnolig, that automates suppression of typographic ligatures](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2884/5001).

The MWE (see image below, and code provided below image) illustrates several instances of failure to perform ligature suppression if -- and apparently also *only if* -- `fontspec` is loaded. Specifically, ligature suppression fails for:

- a word that's followed immediately by a comment (`%`) sign
- the last word in the argument of a command such as `\footnote` and `\section`
- a word that immediately precedes the start of an environment such as `enumerate` and `itemize`
- the final word of an `\item` statement, i.e, the final word before the next `\item` statement and/or the environment's closing `\end{enumerate/itemize}` directive

A common theme of these problems is that they occur if the word in question (plus any trailing punctuation characters) is at the very end of some environment, group, or argument to some macro. In all cases, a "remedy" of sorts is to insert either a space, a blank line, or a space plus something like `\vphantom{x}` [!]. Clearly, these remedies are *not* real solutions but merely kludgy hacks, and I certainly wouldn't contemplate asking users of my package to do implement these hacks.

**My questions** are, then:

- How can I make my lua code more robust to whatever is being done by the `fontspec` pacakge (or some package that's loaded by `fontspec`)?
- Is there a way to load either `fontspec` (or some of the packages called by `fontspec`) to suppress the interference with my lua code?
- Or, have I discovered a bug in `fontspec` (or one or more of the packages loaded by `fontspec`) that needs to be fixed anyway?

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
% If the next line is commented out, everything works fine!
\usepackage{fontspec} 

  \RequirePackage{luatexbase,luacode,expl3}
  % Load lua code
  \directlua{  require("ld-orig.lua")  }  % see below for contents of ld-orig.lua
  % Define the user macro "nolig"
  \providecommand\nolig[2]{ \directlua{
        suppress_liga( "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}",
                       "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}" )}}
  % Provide a ligature suppression rule
  %  (the full package obviously provides many more such macros)
  \nolig{lfful}{lf|ful} % shelfful -> shelf|ful

% Just for this MWE:
   \usepackage[textheight=8cm]{geometry}
   \setlength\parindent{0pt}
   \pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{document}    
Two shelffuls of \TeX-related books: it works!

\bigskip
% word to be de-ligated is followed immediately by % (comment character)
Ligature suppression doesn't work here: shelfful% 

% leaving a space between word and % makes it work even if fontspec is loaded
But it does work in this case: shelfful % 

\bigskip
bad\footnote{This doesn't work: shelfful.} % w/o space 
good\footnote{But this does work: shelfful. \vphantom{x}} % w/ space and \vphantom directive

\bigskip
% Two more problem cases: (i) last word before start of an
% itemize/enumerate environment, (ii) last word of an \item
one shelfful, two shelffuls % no ligature suppression for "shelffuls"
\begin{itemize}
\item shelfful              % no ligature suppression here either
\item shelfful \vphantom{x} % inserting space and \vphantom does the trick...
\end{itemize}

% problem also occurs in arguments of sectioning commands
\section*{sad shelfful}         % again no ligature suppression
\subsection*{happy shelfful }   % adding space at end of argument makes it work!
\end{document}
```

---

Contents of ld-orig.lua:

```lua
--- Credits to Patrick Gundlach, Taco Hoekwater, and Steffen Hildebrandt!
local glyph = node.id('glyph')
local glue = node.id("glue")
local whatsit = node.id("whatsit")
local userdefined

for n,v in pairs(node.whatsits()) do
  if v == 'user_defined' then userdefined = n end
end

local identifier = 123456  -- any unique identifier 
local noliga={}
debug=false  -- default: don't write debugging info to log file

function debug_info(s)
  if debug then
    texio.write_nl(s)
  end
end

local blocknode = node.new(whatsit, userdefined)
blocknode.type = 100
blocknode.user_id = identifier

function process_ligatures(nodes,tail)
  local s={}
  local current_node=nodes
  local build_liga_table =  function(strlen,t)
    local p={}
    for i = 1, strlen do
      p[i]=0
    end
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
      -- debug_info("Match: "..v[3])
      local c= string.find(noliga[v[3]],"|")
      local correction=1
      while c~=nil do
         -- debug_info("Position "..(v[1]+c))
         p[v[1]+c-correction] = 1
         c = string.find(noliga[v[3]],"|",c+1)  
         correction=correction+1
      end   
    end
    -- debug_info("Liga table: "..table.concat(p, ""))
    return p
  end
  local apply_ligatures=function(head,ligatures)
     local i=1
     local hh=head
     local last=node.tail(head)
     for curr in node.traverse_id(glyph,head) do
       if ligatures[i]==1 then
         -- debug_info("Current glyph: "..unicode.utf8.char(curr.char))
         node.insert_before(hh,curr, node.copy(blocknode))
         hh=curr
       end 
       last=curr
       if i==#ligatures then 
         -- debug_info("Leave node list on position: "..i)
         break 
       end
       i=i+1
     end
     if(last~=nil) then
       -- debug_info("Last char: "..unicode.utf8.char(last.char))
     end--]]
  end
  for t in node.traverse(nodes) do
    if t.id==glyph then

      s[#s+1]=string.lower(unicode.utf8.char(t.char))
    elseif t.id== glue then
      local f=string.gsub(table.concat(s,""),"[\\?!,\\.]+","") -- add all interpunction
      local throwliga={}    
      for k, v in pairs(noliga) do
        local count=1
        local match= string.find(f,k)
        while match do
          count=match
          -- debug_info("pattern match: "..f .." - "..k)  
          local n = match + string.len(k)-1
          table.insert(throwliga,{match,n,k})
          match= string.find(f,k,count+1)
        end
      end
      if #throwliga==0 then 
        -- debug_info("No ligature substitution for: "..f)  
      else
        -- debug_info("Do ligature substitution for: "..f)  
        local ligabreaks=build_liga_table(f:len(),throwliga)
        apply_ligatures(current_node,ligabreaks)
      end
      s={}
      current_node=t
    end    
  end
end

function suppress_liga(s,t)
  noliga[s]=t
end

function drop_special_nodes (nodes,tail)
  for t in node.traverse(nodes) do
     if t.id == whatsit and t.subtype == userdefined and t.user_id == identifier then
        node.remove(nodes,t)
        node.free(t)
     end
  end
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("ligaturing", process_ligatures,"Filter ligatures", 1)
```

---

**Postscript**: The solution to the bug described in this posting. The key sequence in the lua code given above is that caused the bug was:

```lua
  for t in node.traverse(nodes) do
     if t.id==glyph then
        s[#s+1]=string.lower(unicode.utf8.char(t.char))
     elseif t.id==glue then
        ...
```

All that was required to fix the bug is to change this code snippet to:

```lua
  for t in node.traverse(nodes) do
     if t.id==glyph then
        s[#s+1]=string.lower(unicode.utf8.char(t.char))
     end
     if ( t.id==glue or t.next==nil or t.id==kern or t.id==rule ) then
        ...
```

The point is that the sequence of characters that needs to be processed by selnolig can end in ways other than just with some amount of (TeX) "glue" (e.g., whitespace). Another way for the sequence to end if the word is the very last item being processed, e.g., if it's the last word in the argument of a command such as `\section{}`; if that's the case, the variable `t.next` will be equal to `nil`. Finally, the two remaining `if` conditions -- `t.id==kern` and `t.id==rule` -- are provided in case a user has inserted a "kern" or "rule" item manually.

The bug fix is incorporated in version 0.220 of the package.

Comment: "...release to the CTAN, but I need to squash a few remaining bugs first...."  Things were different in my day:-)

Comment: If you move the code following the `elseif t.id== glue then` after the end of the `node.traverse()` loop, some problems go away. Didn't check of side effects though. The case with the `%` doesn't have glue at the end so the `t.id == glue` will never be true in that case.

Comment: I think, I’m only speculating here, that the use of `ligaturing` callback is the culprit, you should have used `pre_linebreak_filter` *and* `hpack_filter`, but your code need to be modified, `process_ligatures()` need to return the modified `head`.

Comment: @KhaledHosny - thanks for offering these observations. The reasons I went with a `ligaturing` callback rather than `pre_linebreak_filter` is so that the `\nolig` macros wouldn't operate on a macro called, say, "shelfful" or on a `\label{sec:selffulling}` construct. May I ask you to be a bit more specific about what you mean by "`process_ligatures()` needing to return the modified `head`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\label{sec:selffulling}` stuff shouldn’t be an issue regardless of the callback you use, by the time you are working on the node list it will not be there (in never makes it to the node list, it is handled much earlier).

Comment: If you were to use `pre_linebreak_filter`, the function has to return the modified head, but no return value is needed for the `ligatuering` callback (according to LuaTeX manual).

Comment: I hope my extended answer now reveals why "with fontspec" and "without fontspec" behave differently. Any more questions?

Comment: @topskip - Thanks so much for the various rounds of analysis you've applied. I've learned a lot from your work -- and I've come to realize I still have more programming to do!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :) Just let me know if I can be of more help - I can't promise anything but I'll try.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me try to analyze the problem: You call the `ligaturing` over and over again, but sometimes the callback doesn't seem to have any effect. I'd like to take a look at two cases: the footnotes:

```
bad\footnote{This doesn't work: shelfful.} % w/o space 
good\footnote{But this does work: shelfful. \vphantom{x}} % w/ space and \vphantom directive
```

I'll have a look at the node list that is passed to the ligaturing callbacks with my small module  [viznodelist](https://gist.github.com/pgundlach/556247).

I change the lua code slightly at the entrance point to `process_ligatures()`:

```lua
...
require("viznodelist")
function process_ligatures(nodes,tail)
  counter = counter or 0
  counter = counter + 1
  viznodelist.nodelist_visualize(nodes,string.format("liga%d.gv",counter))
```

The first footnote ('bad') looks like this:

[image: nodelist,complete]

with the detail (top right)

[image]

while the "good" nodelist looks like this:

[image]

Now looking at the code:

```lua
  for t in node.traverse(nodes) do
    if t.id==glyph then

      s[#s+1]=string.lower(unicode.utf8.char(t.char))
    elseif t.id== glue then
    ...
      (process ligatures)
    ...
    end
  end
```

makes it clear that only a `glue` activates the ligature processing.

I'd suggest using a different kind of looping for ligature processing.

The difference between `fontspec` activated or not is the following: with fontspec deactivated, the ligaturing callback disables all ligaturing. What you see is not the effect of the command `\nolig`, but a general "no ligature" mode. Try words like `fluffiest fish` and you see that. With fontspec enabled, the result is "always ligatures" unless you block them with the code you use.

So the ligaturing callback is not the perfect way to deal with the situation, I am afraid. You could however call `node.ligaturing()` at the beginning of the callback and then do what you are doing. But that would probably interfere with fontspec.

Comment: +1 for the viznodelist module!! Your detailed analysis is very helpful indeed. Real quick: (i) Would you mind posting new images, that also show what happens -- if anything -- between the "f" and "f" in "shelfful"? (Currently, the images start with the second "f", but don't show anything to the left of that second "f".)  (ii) If it is *only* glue that activates the (de)ligaturing loop, why do the ligature suppression algorithms work *unless* `fontspec` (or, possibly, one or more of the packages loaded by `fontspec`) isn't loaded?

Comment: Many thanks for the expande answer. I've familiarized myself  with the `viznodelist` module. As you've noted, the string `shelfful%` generates the same viz-output irrespective of whether `fontspec` is loaded or not; specifically, there's a "glyph box" for the first `f`, a "disc box" (for the discretionary hyphen), and a "glyph box" for the second `f`. However, we know that *with* `fontspec` loaded, there will be an "ff" ligature, whereas there won't be a ligature in the case without `fontspec`. So there must be a difference lurking somewhere not caught by `viznodelist`. :-(