# Strange interaction between fontspec, lua and pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, fontspec, lua

While trying to combine some Lua code with plots written in `pgfplots` something went completely wrong. I have no idea what causes the problem, as the error message is a bit opaque to me. Here is the example which compiles nicely in `luatex` without the `fontspec` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
some text
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    file = io.open("test.txt", "r")
    text = file:read("*all")
    return tex.print(text) 
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{readtxt()} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[] coordinates {(0.0, 0.0) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With `fontspec` enabled the first error messages of a total of 58 are:

```
! LuaTeX error ...)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-font-def.lua:239: att
empt to call field 'suffix' (a nil value).
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.26   \end{axis}

The lua interpreter ran into a problem, so the
remainder of this lua chunk will be ignored.

! Font \EU2/lmr/m/n/8=file:lmroman8-regular:script=latn;+trep;+tlig; at 8pt not
 loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.26   \end{axis}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
```

Somehow there is some negative interaction between the three components, Lua, `pgfplots` and `fontspec`. Individually they all work nicely. Some interaction was reported in this question: [Bad interaction between fontspec and some lua code that performs string-related search and replace operations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107376/bad-interaction-between-fontspec-and-some-lua-code-that-performs-string-related) but this seems unrelated.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with pgfplots: You get the same error if you simply try to change the font after your `\directlua` e.g. by issuing a `\tiny`.

The source of the problem is the name of your file handle. Probably luaotfload is using this name too. Every thing works if I change the name to e.g. fileA:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.txt}
some text
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{luacode*}
  function readtxt()
    fileA = io.open("test.txt", "r") --changed
    text = fileA:read("*all")
    return tex.print(text)
  end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\directlua{readtxt()}

\tiny abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The lua scoping rules have bitten me here. Turns out that lua uses 'global by default' and indeed, `otfl-font-def.lua` uses a variable called `file` which is overwritten by the declaration in `readtxt()`.

Comment: Always use local variables in Lua code, so `local file = ....` and do not pollute the global namespace with macro names. In ConTeXt, the standard practice is to use `thirddats = thirddata or {}` and then `function thirddata.readtxt`, etc.