# How can I highlight ligatures?

Tags: color, highlighting, ligatures, fun

I'd like to highlight all the ligatures used in a document similar to the image below

[image: ligatures]

as an attempt to show off some of TeX's tender loving care for the font being used.

Is there a way to do this automatically?  My guess is that it would be *much* easier in XeTeX, but any automatic solution is welcome.

Comment: This is essentially the same as [This one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120100/xetex-arabic-vowels) which means xetex may not help as much as you want. luatex perhaps....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - it would seem so -- since ligatures are essentially just another glyph in the font, no different from 'normal' letters (to my understanding).  LuaTeX raises interesting possibilities, since it can perhaps peer into the fonts being used and then 'mark' ligatures, inserting `\color` tokens as necessary...  (but wouldn't that still break the input stream, as feared in the linked Q?)  Just thinking out loud.  Perhaps this needs to be a two-pass process - once to generate marked TeX (perhaps from Python/Lua/etc.) and once to compile the document.

Comment: If you are prepared to modify the font you could use a .vf file and add colour specials into the vf description of each ligature. Would be quite a bit of work and you'd have to do it for each font.

Comment: There is some code on site that works to suppress ligatures ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48516/how-to-suppress-the-operation-of-a-luatex-defined-macro-on-a-string-if-the-strin) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107376/bad-interaction-between-fontspec-and-some-lua-code-that-performs-string-related)).  It might be a starting point or modified to color them rather than suppressing them.

Comment: It  might even be dead easy with the `ligaturing` callback.  I've never used it so can't say for sure.

Comment: @ScottH. This is a LuaTeX keyword of sorts, I presume?  (I've only experience with LaTeX / XeLaTeX.)

Comment: I'm probably not the one to explain, but callbacks in lua provide points in the processing of the document where one can insert their own code.  There are a lot of them. One is the `ligaturing` callback, which would let you run code when the ligatures are actually being inserted.  [Here](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf) is a document that gives an overview.

Comment: @ScottH. I honestly think `ligaturing` is the best bet without insane amounts of TeXpert hackery.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using Luatex, you can insert color literals to highlight ligatures.
Save this snippet as `color-ligatures.lua`:

```lua
documentdata                  = documentdata or { }
documentdata.color_ligatures  = { }
local color_ligatures         = documentdata.color_ligatures

color_ligatures.color         = { r = 0xee/255,
                                  g = 0x31/255,
                                  b = 0x09/255, }

local stringformat            = string.format

local copynode                = node.copy
local insertnodeafter         = node.insert_after
local insertnodebefore        = node.insert_before
local newnode                 = node.new
local traversenodes           = node.traverse
local traversenodetype        = node.traverse_id

local nodecodes               = nodes.nodecodes

local glyph_t                 = nodecodes.glyph
local disc_t                  = nodecodes.disc
local hlist_t                 = nodecodes.hlist
local whatsit_t               = nodecodes.whatsit
local pdf_literal_t           = 8 -- change to 16 on TexLive 2016 (luatex 0.95)

local get_color = function ()
  local color   = color_ligatures.color
  local push    = stringformat ("%.3g %.3g %.3g rg",
                                color.r,
                                color.g,
                                color.b)
  local pop     = "0 g"
  return push, pop
end

local pdf_literal = newnode(whatsit_t, pdf_literal_t)

local cbk = function (hd)
  local pushcolor, popcolor = get_color()
  local push, pop = copynode(pdf_literal), copynode(pdf_literal)
  push.mode, push.data = 1, pushcolor
  pop.mode,  pop.data  = 1, popcolor

  for line in traversenodetype(hlist_t, hd) do
    local hlist = line.list
    for n in traversenodes(hlist) do
      --- locate ligatures
      if  n.id == glyph_t and n.components then
        --- surround with color literals
        local before, after = copynode(push), copynode(pop)
        hlist = insertnodebefore(hlist, n, before)
        hlist = insertnodeafter (hlist, n, after)
      elseif n.id == disc_t then
        local replace = n.replace
        if replace and replace.components then
          local before, after = copynode(push), copynode(pop)
          hlist = insertnodebefore(hlist, n, before)
          hlist = insertnodeafter (hlist, n, after)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return hd
end

local hook    = "post_linebreak_filter"
local active  = false

color_ligatures.enable = function ()
  if active == false then
    luatexbase.add_to_callback (hook, cbk, "my.color_ligatures")
    active = true
  end
end

color_ligatures.disable = function ()
  if active == true then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback (hook, "my.color_ligatures")
    active = false
  end
end

color_ligatures.set_color = function (r, g, b)
  color_ligatures.color = { r = (tonumber(r, 16) or 0) / 255,
                            g = (tonumber(g, 16) or 0) / 255,
                            b = (tonumber(b, 16) or 0) / 255, }
end
```

Now you can define some macros that toggle the callback on demand by
wrapping the functions `enable()` and `disable()`.
For example:

```
\input luaotfload.sty  % in latex: \usepackage{luaotfload}
\directlua{dofile "color-ligatures.lua"}

%% uncomment the next line for node mode (default in luaotfload):
%\font\mainfont="file:Iwona-Regular.otf" at 30pt \mainfont

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% enabling/disabling the colorizer
\def\startcolorligatures{%
  \directlua{documentdata.color_ligatures.enable()}%
}

\def\stopcolorligatures{%
  \endgraf %% paragraph-based callback
  \directlua{documentdata.color_ligatures.disable()}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% changings colors (expects octets in hexadecimal)
\def\setligaturecolor#1#2#3{%%-> rgb values
  \directlua{documentdata.color_ligatures.set_color("#1", "#2", "#3")}
}
```

Usage:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% demo
%%
%% a) inactive
before a ff b ffi c ffl d

%% b) activate, using default color
\startcolorligatures
during a ff b ffi c ffl d

%% c) change color to blue
\setligaturecolor{0}{0}{bb}
different color a ff b ffi c ffl d
\stopcolorligatures

%% d) inactive again
after a ff b ffi c ffl d

\bye
```

Output:

[image: result of demo]

EDIT: Recognize ligatures differently so it works in *node* mode as well.

Comment: This is really awesome!! I'm still interested in other solutions (plainTeX (shudder), XeTeX, ConTeXt, etc), but I'm curious -- did you look into the `ligaturing` hook as described in the comments?  Was there a misunderstanding in its purpose, or did it just turn out to be messier than you'd think?

Comment: Shouldn't the `ff` in "different" also be blue?

Comment: @Charles Staats good catch, I totally ignored break points. Should be fixed now (see preview image).

Comment: @Sean Allred I don’t use Xetex, so I can’t help you there. Context otoh requires only minor modifications since it is Luatex based as well. *did you look into the ligaturing hook?* -- the ``ligaturing`` callback is for inserting ligatures but if you want to colorize them, they need to be present already. Thus, the choice of the ``post_linebreak_filter``.

Comment: Thank you. This is not only fun, but also useful for familiarizing oneself with a new font and for checking whether a document has problems of the ‘shelfful’ kind. But while it works with any font in the article class, in the book class I get an error like `Font \EU2/BemboBookMTPro(0)/m/it/10.95=/home/me/.fonts/Monotype not loadable: metric data not found or bad` iff the font has a space in its file name.

Comment: @therese that’s an issue when using Latex with Luaotfload 2.2. It is worked around in the [dev version](https://github.com/phi-gamma/luaotfload) but has not made it on CTAN yet. Removing those spaces should help to some extent.

Comment: @phg awesome script. Thank you. If I may report "a bug": compiling this `{\color{blue} blablup ff fl blablup}` breaks the coloring after the ligatures.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Yes, I’m being cheap not using the colorstack but injecting pdfliterals instead.

Comment: @phg Well, does not matter, as I won't print with colored ligatures. Just noticed that, when ligatures got marked in my color-links-TOC. Great work anyway.

Comment: @PhilippGesang I've been using your script extensively in the past, thanks a lot! But some updates of the past years seem to have broken it. I get error message: `color-ligatures.lua:41: You cannot set field data in a node of type whatsit.` also: `\newpage ...k \@nobreakfalse \everypar {}\fi \par \vfil \penalty -\@M ` Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @Huugo: I could fix the error message `color-ligatures.lua:41: You cannot set field data in a node of type whatsit.` with following change: `color-ligatures.lua:24 local pdf_literal_t           = 16` (change the value 8 to 16 for pdf_literal_t).