# Color all vowels differently in a LaTeX document

Tags: color, loops

Is it possible to give the letters a,e,i,o,u,y a different color in a piece of text? For instance, color all the a's red, the e's blue, the i's green, etc.

**EDIT:** *Without doing it manually of course.*

Comment: How big is this piece of text? Can you be more precise about your need?

Comment: Coloring all vowels is more difficult than just coloring a,e,i,o,u,y. For instance, _y_ is a vowel in "tyre" but not in "hay".

Comment: Just want to link these two questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120397/17423

Answer (score 37):

[image]

Requires xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \vowelsclass


\XeTeXcharclass `\a \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\e \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\i \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\o \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\u \vowelsclass

\XeTeXcharclass `\A \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\E \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\I \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\O \vowelsclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\U \vowelsclass


\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \vowelsclass = {\bgroup\color{blue}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 1 \vowelsclass = {\bgroup\color{blue}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 2 \vowelsclass = {\bgroup\color{blue}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 3 \vowelsclass = {\bgroup\color{blue}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \vowelsclass = {\bgroup\color{blue}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \vowelsclass 0 = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \vowelsclass 1 = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \vowelsclass 2 = {\egroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \vowelsclass 4095 = {\egroup}


\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight.

\end{document}
```

---

Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) orginally it was 255

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.

Comment: @Marijn oh I changed another answer about that recently, I guess  should search the site (it would have been fine just to have fixed it, but I'll do it now:-)

Comment: @Marijn I borrowed your text, thanks

Answer (score 34):

This is just for practicing with LaTeX3 code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorize}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set:cpn { maryjane_color_#1: } { \textcolor{#2}{#1} }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_maryjane_text_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\changecolors}{ O{aeiou} m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_maryjane_text_tl { #2 }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } 
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_maryjane_text_tl { ##1 } { \use:c { maryjane_color_##1: } }
   }
  \l_maryjane_text_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\colorize{a}{red}
\colorize{e}{blue}
\colorize{i}{green}
\colorize{o}{yellow}
\colorize{u}{blue!30}

\begin{document}

\changecolors{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\changecolors[a]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

In the optional argument you can specify a subset of the declared letters. If you specify an undeclared letter (with `\colorize`), it will be gobbled.

[image]

Comment: Very nice.  So this works in the style of `\textbf{...}` or `\textcolor{...}`.  How would you modify this to make it work in the style of `\bfseries` or `\color{...}`?

Comment: @A.Ellett I need to get the text before starting to change the colors.

Answer (score 4):

A `luatex` solution to the problem:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y',
          'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y'}

vowels_char = {}
for _, value in pairs(vowels) do
  vowels_char[#vowels_char + 1] = string.byte(value)
end

function table.contains(table, element)
  for _, value in pairs(table) do
    if value == element then
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end

function color_vowels(head)
  for n in node.traverse_id(node.id("glyph"), head) do
    if table.contains(vowels_char, n.char) then
        local n1, n2
        n1 = node.new(node.id("whatsit"), node.subtype("pdf_literal"))
        n2 = node.new(node.id("whatsit"), node.subtype("pdf_literal"))
        n1.data = "q 1 0 0 rg"
        n1.mode = 1
        node.insert_before(head, n, n1)
        n2.data = " Q"
        n2.mode = 1
        node.insert_after(head, n, n2)
    end
  end
  return head
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", color_vowels, "Color vowels")
luatexbase.add_to_callback("hpack_filter", color_vowels, "Color vowels")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumped Over the lazy dog

\hbox{The quick brown fox jumped Over the lazy dog}

$a^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A few notes about the code. `string.byte` returns the ASCII value of its argument. Color change is done at `pdf` level with a 'whatits' `pdf_literal` node (`q` is a kind of begin group and `Q` a kind of end group in `pdf`, `rg` is the `rgb` model for non stroking operations).

A final note: my method does not work with inline math.

Comment: ...or more precisely works too good, even for inline math :)