# highlighting vowels using a background color

Tags: color, backgrounds, loops

Is it possible to give the letters a,e,i,o,u,y a different background color in a piece of text by using a loop or package? For instance, give the a's a red background, the e's a blue background, etc. Without changing the background of the other letters in the text.

Comment: To the extent that you are trying to distinguish vowels from consonants, a simple version will have problems with 'y'.

Comment: XeTeX can do that.  Let me find the reference

Comment: See p.14 in http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf  Is that what you need?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) question: [Color all vowels differently in a LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138706)

Comment: In fact, you seem to have the same user name. Why is the answered question not sufficient for you?

Comment: What's different (slightly) is the *background* colour.  The xetex charclass solution in the referenced question changes *foreground* colours.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138706/color-all-vowels-differently-in-a-latex-document), here is a way to use the same XeTeX extensions to put in **background** colours.  I've only done "a" and "e" but it could obviously be extended.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1
\newXeTeXintercharclass \tta \XeTeXcharclass `\a \tta
\newXeTeXintercharclass \tte \XeTeXcharclass `\e \tte
%
\setbox2=\hbox{a}
\XeTeXinterchartoks    0 \tta = {\rlap{\textcolor{green}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \tta \tta = {\rlap{\textcolor{green}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \tte \tta = {\rlap{\textcolor{green}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks  255 \tta = {\rlap{\textcolor{green}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\setbox2=\hbox{e}
\XeTeXinterchartoks    0 \tte = {\rlap{\textcolor{orange}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \tta \tte = {\rlap{\textcolor{orange}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \tte \tte = {\rlap{\textcolor{orange}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}
\XeTeXinterchartoks  255 \tte = {\rlap{\textcolor{orange}{\vrule height \ht2 width \wd2 depth \dp2}}}

The awful weary green fox jumped over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the XeTeX reference for details of what `\XeTeXinterchartoks` does.

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the answers to two questions yields a simple solution:

Leo Liu's answer to:
 - [soul: broken highlighting with xcolor when using \selectcolormodel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48501/2693)

and egreg's answer to:
 - [Color all vowels differently in a LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138706/2693)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % use normalem to protect \emph
\newcommand\hl[1]{\bgroup\markoverwith
  {\textcolor{#1}{\rule[-.5ex]{2pt}{2.5ex}}}\ULon}
  \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorize}{mm}
 {
  \cs_set:cpn { maryjane_color_#1: } { \hl{#2}{#1} }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_maryjane_text_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{\changecolors}{ O{aeiou} m }
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_maryjane_text_tl { #2 }
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } 
   {
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_maryjane_text_tl { ##1 } { \use:c { maryjane_color_##1: } }
   }
  \l_maryjane_text_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\colorize{a}{red}
\colorize{e}{blue}
\colorize{i}{green}
\colorize{o}{yellow}
\colorize{u}{brown!30}

\begin{document}

\changecolors{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\changecolors[a]{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]