# Is there a way to specify that some given letters are always in bold?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I am writing an article, which requires the letters 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' are always showed in bold. Given the following TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

% What should be put here?

\begin{article}
You can say Hi as Hello.
\end{article}
```

**The default result is:** You can say Hi as Hello.

**What I really want is:** Y**ou** c**a**n s**a**y H**i** **a**s H**e**ll**o**.

Comment: I remember I have seen an exact question here and many good answers but searching... Phew.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Perhaps something similar to this: [Color all vowels differently in a LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/138706/5764) and possibly [Highlighting vowels using a background color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146596/5764)

Comment: @Werner Exactly. Thanks. You are a good *ninja* :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using XeTeX then your task is exactly solved by XeTeX primitives `\XeTeXcharclass` and `\XeTeXinterchartoks`. Read the manual of XeTeX. For letters 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' the setting looks like:

```
\newXeTeXintercharclass \mycharclassbf
\XeTeXcharclass `\a =\mycharclassbf
\XeTeXcharclass `\e =\mycharclassbf
\XeTeXcharclass `\i =\mycharclassbf
\XeTeXcharclass `\o =\mycharclassbf
\XeTeXcharclass `\u =\mycharclassbf

\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \mycharclassbf = {\bgroup\bf}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassbf 0 = {\egroup}   
\XeTeXinterchartoks 255 \mycharclassbf = {\bgroup\bf}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \mycharclassbf 255 = {\egroup}   

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate = 1

You can say Hi as hello.

\bye
```

Comment: All roads lead to *plain* TeX. `:-)` +1

Comment: You can compare my answer with the page 120 of my book TeX for pragmatic http://petr.olsak.net/tpp.html . There is no difference.

Comment: Note that the word boundary class currently has the number 4095 (since 2016) instead of 255.

Answer (score 2):

Let me present a small snippet in LuaTeX. We pass an argument and selected letters to the Lua core, where the snippet decomposes it at a character level and wraps the preselected letters only by the `\malbf` command.

Words to be marked are tagged, I didn't expect a TeX command, I presumed plain text. I enclose a small example with English (requested letters by OP) and Czech text (all the graphemes).

We can also check out the output in the terminal, it writes:

```
H\malbf{e}ll\malbf{o} W\malbf{o}rld! Y\malbf{ou} c\malbf{a}n s\malbf{a}y H\malbf{i} \malbf{a}s H\malbf{e}ll\malbf{o}.
Č\malbf{au} d\malbf{ě}ck\malbf{a}, j\malbf{a}k s\malbf{e} d\malbf{a}ř\malbf{í}?
```

If we would like to see different strategy how to preserve ligatures and kerning pairs of the formatted letters (I remove all the `}\malbf{` sequences in this example), please see Version 2 of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237005/48028). I mentioned one other method  of the possible strategies there (I used a variable for font switching). In this example, we've got `Č\malbf{au}` instead of `Č\malbf{a}\malbf{u}`, and `Y\malbf{ou}` instead of `Y\malbf{o}\malbf{u}`.

I enclose the source code of the snippet and a preview of the PDF file. We run `lualatex mal-letters.tex`.

```
% lualatex mal-letters.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luatextra} % luacode

\begin{luacode*}
function boldme () -- the core function
letters=tex.toks[1] -- some more/other letters?
text=tex.toks[0] -- text taken from TeX
towrite="" -- an empty string
markerbegin="\\malbf{" -- a command to be used as a marker
markerend="}"

for i=1,unicode.utf8.len(text) do -- decomposition of text
s=unicode.utf8.sub(text, i, i) -- actual character
  isthere=nil -- initial value, no, character is not among letters
  for j=1,unicode.utf8.len(letters) do -- test if it is
     if unicode.utf8.sub(letters, j, j)==s then isthere=1; break end
     end -- for, j, is character between selected letters?
  if isthere then -- to be bold, or not?
     towrite=towrite..markerbegin..s..markerend -- yes, it is to be empasized in bold
        else
     towrite=towrite..s -- no, that character is not among selected letters
     end -- if, isthere
end -- for, i, decomposition of input text  
  -- combine the commands together
  -- e.g. \malbf{a}\malbf{e} -> \malbf{ae}
  towrite=unicode.utf8.gsub(towrite, markerend..markerbegin, "")
  -- writing result to the terminal and to the document
  io.write(towrite) -- information shipped to the terminal
  tex.sprint(towrite) -- information shipped to the document
end -- function, boldme
\end{luacode*}
\def\malbf#1{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}
\def\markit#1{\toks0{#1}\directlua{boldme()}}
\def\tomark#1{\toks1{#1}}

\begin{document}
% Text in English, selected letters.
\tomark{aeiou}
Some text before. \markit{Hello World! You can say Hi as Hello.} More text after.

% An example with Czech graphemes.
\tomark{aáeéěiíoóuúůyý}
Text in the middle. \markit{Čau děcka, jak se daří?} End of story.
\end{document}
```

[image: An example with English and Czech text]